# How do I turn off this line in weight painting?

Tags: 3d-view, armature, weight-painting, visibility

I was editing the weights and I **guess** I accidentally pressed a hotkey or something. Now whenever I try and remove some weight, the brush changes to this weird delayed brush that removes weights after I passed over it and I have to keep going back and forth with it instead of just wiggling my mouse over an area like I always do. What did I press so I can avoid it and how do I go back to the normal brush?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please try and remove any excess white space in any images before you upload in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What has happened is that you have activated a feature called **Stabilize Stroke**, which can be found in the *Active Tool* Tab of the Properties Panel, under the **Stroke** Section. It is very easy to enable this feature by accident, by inadvertently pressing its shortcut, which is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>. The reason it is slow is because it gives up draw performance in order to facilitate a more precise line result. The same feature exists in Sculpt Mode, and can be accessed the same way.

[image]