# How to disable blue line in weight paint brush

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, brushes

Found this weird line with the weight paint brush, Does anybody know how to disable it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the selected bone that you're trying to weight paint where the armature has been set to 'Stick' type under the Viewport display properties.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the bone what I mean is the brush why is there a blue line every time I pull the brush?

Comment: Ah! I see. See if https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183494/how-do-i-turn-off-this-line-in-weight-painting helps. It's called "Stabilize Stroke".

Comment: Ah took awhile for me to figure out, Thanks!

Comment: We got there in the end! :^)